# Reopen 388541 that asks the why's not the how's

Tags: discussion, duplicates

This [question of mine](https://askubuntu.com/q/388541/169736) was closed on the basis that I'm asking the same question... I'm not. I specifically ask the "Why `apt-get install update` fails" (which normally people try to update their systems) meanwhile the other question address how to solve the issue where the package is simply misspelled or not available.... **I'm not trying to solve anything!** That questions are "related" doesn't mean that are the same! In 3 months it gathered 3k views so explaining the why to the whole population of internet denizen is more useful that blindly trying to solve a problem they don't have.

`apt-get install update` is a silly mistake most people do and the only solution is explain that `install` expects a `package` and since there's isn't a package called "update" it fails and how to do the action they meant to do: `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get install package`, the duplicated doesn't address the question in the way I phrased it.

The answer I offered is the proof that both questions are addressing an specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. As the first close voter, I will say, **it was a mistake for me to have voted to close this.** I've voted to reopen it.

I do recommend the question be changed somewhat to clarify what it is really asking. (I've edited it toward this end, but you might think of a better way to improve it.) I had interpreted the `update` in `install update` as a [metasyntactic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) (standing in for whatever package name the user wished to upgrade) rather that an indication that the question was for the benefit of people who actually type the exact text `sudo apt-get install update`.

If you have information about when people have actually made this mistake, you may want to link to it in [the question itself](https://askubuntu.com/q/388541). Or if you don't want to do that, then perhaps here: it may convince people that the special case this question covers is significant. Either way though, I realize now that your question is *not* really a special case of the question against which we duped it.

I suspect we may already have had a question about how to use `apt-get` in general. So this might end up re-duped to such a question. But I'm not sure what (if any) question that would be, and I see no reason to keep it closed now.